# Are inotify events guaranteed to come in the right order?

Tags: inotify

I have a single thread writing a stream of data into files in a directory.  The data stream can pause for any length of time just as easily as it writes a continuous trickle of data.  It writes one file at a time and whenever the file grows too large, it closes the file and begins a new one.  The files should therefore be read in a particular order to reconstruct the stream.

Separately I have another process (possibly several) following the stream of data using [inotify](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html) to trigger reads.  This allows a one-to-many distribution of data as well as the option to replay the stream at any time.

I'm concerned about how to correctly handle the changeover of files in the readers.  I don't want the reader to start processing the next file until the last has been completely written to.

Assuming a single directory level inotify watch, are inotify events guarantee to be reported in the order they were generated? *They are being generated by a single thread.  There is a provable order to them*.  More specifically, are `IN_MODIFY` and `IN_CREATE` guaranteed to happen in the same order even though they technically apply to different inodes?